# How to check whether an input is numeric or not in multiple TextBoxes?

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, input, numeric

I am currently working on an exam in programming using VB, and I am trying to make two subs for only text input and only numeric values. To code that for one textbox is easy, but I cant seem to remember how to do it for multiple textboxes where I use a sub to call the If sentence up. (I use the handles textchange in VB to control input)

Here is the code I used for checking one textbox:

```
If Not Regex.Match(txtRegansnr.Text, "^[a-å]*$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Success Then

MsgBox("Kun bokstaver tillatt.", , "Feil")
        txtRegansnr.Clear()
        txtRegansnr.Focus()

End If
```

I have tried to modify this code but cant get it to work like I want it to.

Comment: Pass the text boxes to the subs as parameters by reference.

Comment: Is it wpf, winforms of webforms? Please add appropriate tag.

Comment: Dont see how that is relevant to my question but ok.

Answer (score 0):

Put this inside the textchanged event handler:

```
Dim txtbox as TextBox = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)

If Not Regex.Match(txtbox.Text, "^[a-å]*$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Success Then

  MsgBox("Kun bokstaver tillatt.", , "Feil")
  txtbox.Clear()
  txtbox.Focus()

End If
```

Append all textboxes to the `Handles` list of the above handler:

```
Sub TextChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtRegansnr.TextChanged, txtBox1.TextChanged, txtBox2.TextChanged, ...
```